# Using key vault reference from different resource group in azure function appsettings

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am using below code to use key vault reference in azure function app which works fine.

```
'@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${keyVaultName};SecretName=SECRETNAME)'
```

However, if key vault is from different resource group than below code does throw error.

```
resourceId(keyVaultRg,'@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${keyVaultName};SecretName=SECRETNAME)')
```

'Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. Current function arguments 'RESOURCE-GROUP,@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=KEYVAULTNAME;SecretName=SECRETNAME)'